# How to hide a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to hide the following `div` with jQuery?

HTML:

```
    <div class="BottomSmMargin MiniCheckDiv">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.BottomSmMargin.MiniCheckDiv').hide();
```

Notice there is no space between the two classes here.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you can use to qualify (the selector), but [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) (or [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)) is probably what you're looking for.

```
$('div.BottomSmMargin').hide();
// or
$('div.MiniCheckDiv').hide();
// or both
$('div.BottomSmMargin').hasClass('MiniCheckDiv').hide();
```

Comment: And even `$('.BottomSmMargin.MiniCheckDiv').hide()`, cf. @Delan Azabani's answer. Didn't know this one :)

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

Always useful: have a look at the [jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/). There you can find the following functions:

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

and

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems, your DOM may not be ready. Make sure that you put it within the document ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.BottomSmMargin.MiniCheckDiv').hide();
});
```